# socket select always return zero

Tags: ios, sockets, select

i create a socket to receive server data, and adopt non-blocking mode but i'm confuse why select always return zero? this make my player play or pause for a moment,
  If you require any further information please let me know.

```
int ret = 0;
int timeout = 0;
while(http->work_flag)
{
    fd_set  readSet;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 80*1000;
    FD_ZERO( &readSet );
    FD_SET( http->fd, &readSet );
    ret = select(http->fd + 1,&readSet,0,0,&tv);
    printf("%d\r\n",ret);
    if ( ret > 0 ) {
        ret = recv(http->fd,buf,size,0);
        if( ret <= 0 ){
            ret = -1;       
        }
        else {
            http->total_bytes += ret;
            http->continue_pkt++;   
        }
        return ret;
    }   
    else if( ret < 0 ) {
        http->continue_pkt = 0;
        return  -1;
    }   
    else if( ret == 0 ) {
        http->continue_pkt = 0;
        //time out
        timeout++;
        if( timeout > 12*30 ) //30seconds
            return -1;//timeout
    }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: may be help full for you https://discussions.apple.com/message/7815634?messageID=7815634#7815634?messageID=7815634

Comment: If 'ret' is zero you should return zero, so that the caller knows to close the FD. At the moment you are conflating end of stream with an error condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem if you get rid of your loop completely and let `select()` manage the timeout for you?

```
fd_set  readSet;
struct timeval tv;

tv.tv_sec = 30;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

FD_ZERO( &readSet );
FD_SET( http->fd, &readSet );

int ret = select(http->fd + 1, &readSet, 0, 0, &tv);
printf("%d\r\n", ret);

if( ret <= 0 )
{
    // error or timeout
    http->continue_pkt = 0;
    return -1;
}

ret = recv(http->fd, buf, size, 0);
if( ret <= 0 )
{
    // error or disconnect
    return -1;
}

http->total_bytes += ret;
http->continue_pkt++;   
return ret;
```

The only reason to call `select()` in a loop with small timeouts is if you are trying to cause your reading logic to abort as quick as possible.  For that, you could create a separate pipe via `pipe()` and put it in the same `fd_set` with your socket, and then write something to the pipe to make `select()` "wake up" when needed.  When `select()` returns `> 0`, the code can check if the pipe was signaled and exit without calling `recv()` if it was.

Comment: it's will also happend, but if i get rid of timeout,and set tv.tv_usec = 800*1000;it can work well.

Comment: but if ret < 0, that's will make reconnection.